# Error when trying to compile a zero-sized record variable in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm creating an array of records dependent on the number of port connections made in a component. The actual component works fine when the number of connections is 1 or more, but does not work when no connections are made. Looking for input on how to resolve or workaround.

Here is the error:

[image]

Below is a MWE:

```
model RecordIssue
  record Record
    Real a=1;
  end Record;

  parameter Integer nPorts=0 annotation (Dialog(connectorSizing=true));

  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPorts_a ports_a[nPorts];

  // declare record array instance for each port connection
  parameter Record[nPorts] recordInstance={Record() for i in 1:nPorts};

  // this next line is an issue only when nPorts = 0 or no connections made
  Real test[:]=recordInstance[:].a;
end RecordIssue;
```

The expected/desired behavior would be for the variable `test` to not exist when `nPorts=0`, which is the normal behavior for something like `Real test[:] = {1.0 for i in 1:nPorts};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to ensure that the record variable is never empty and avoid access when `nPorts` is zero.

```
model RecordIssue
  record Record
    Real a=1;
  end Record;

  record Dummy
    extends Record(a=Modelica.Constants.inf);
  end Dummy;

  parameter Integer nPorts = 0 annotation (Dialog(connectorSizing=true));

  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPorts_a ports_a[nPorts];

  // declare record array and ensure that at least one exists
  parameter Record[max(nPorts, 1)] recordInstance = if nPorts > 0 then {Record() for i in 1:nPorts} else {Dummy()};
  
  // decide here if recordInstance shall be used
  Real test[nPorts] = if nPorts > 0 then recordInstance[:].a else fill(0, 0);
end RecordIssue;
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, I realized another simple workaround for me was to just to make the "test" variable conditional and just add "if nPorts > 0" at the end of its declaration.

Comment: Note that this is not allowed in pedantic mode. Conditional variables can only be used in connect statements when pedantic mode is on.

Comment: FYI I tried a pedantic check and it seemed ok. In my situation, my "test" variable is more of a summary variable/record, so its not used by any downstream equations etc., so as far as I can tell its ok.